# Display some chart.js in the popup of chrome's extensions

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chart.js

I am trying to display some dynamic charts from chart.js in the popup of my chrome extension.

Here is my minimal HTML file:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div>
                <canvas id="chart"></canvas>
            </div>
        </div>
        <p id='test'></p>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='chart.js'>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='popup.js'>
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And my minimal script, adding the data into the chart:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function()
{
    var ctx = document.getElementById("chart").getContext('2d');
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'doughnut',
        data: {
            labels: [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' ],
                datasets: [{
                backgroundColor: [
                    "#59be5b",
                    "#d56328",
                    "#ff1b2d",
                    "#0078d7"
                ],
                data: [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
            }]
        }
    });

    document.getElementById('test').textContent = 'SUCCEED';
});
```

Now my popup is blank, there is no chart and the test element has no content. Moreover, there is no console output (no error).

How must I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have some syntex error , try the following code:

popup.html

```
<html>
<head>     
    <script type='text/javascript' src='chart.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='popup.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div>
            <canvas id="chart"></canvas>
        </div>
    </div>
    <p id='test'></p>
</body>
```

manifest:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "minimum_chrome_version": "23",
  "name": "test!",
  "description": "test",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_title": "Click here!"
    },
 "permissions": [],
 "background": {    }
}
```

popup.js is the same...

I test it and it's show the chart in my pop-up

Good luck.

Comment: Oh right. I' ve forgotten the end tag of the script. It was a bit confusing because there was no error in the console. I didn't know that HMTL error weren't shown in it. Thank you.